# getting adapter type mismatch in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

basically i am trying to create a recycler view and this the main activity

i am getting error at

`recyclerView.adapter = adapter`

```
package com.example.newsorning
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val items = fetchData()
  val adapter = NewsListAdapter(items)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

}
private fun fetchData():ArrayList<String>{
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in 0 until 100){
        list.add("item $i")
    }
    return list
}
}
```

this is where i created adpater
//newsListadapter

```
  package com.example.newsorning

  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  import android.view.LayoutInflater
   import android.view.View
  import android.view.ViewGroup
  import android.widget.TextView
  
  class NewsListAdapter(private val item:ArrayList<String>): 
  RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsViewHolder>() {

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): NewsViewHolder {
 
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.item_news,p0,false)
  
     return  NewsViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return item.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: NewsViewHolder, p1: Int) {
 val currentItem = item[p1]
    p0.titleView.text = currentItem
    }
}
class NewsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
     val titleView : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleView)
 }
```

Comment: Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, so you should stop using it - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration and remove this unnecessary  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

and then try

This might help you, if not share the screenshot your error

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to you using the old, deprecated support library RecyclerView (android.support.v7) instead of the Jetpack RecyclerView (androidx). Maybe one of the libraries you're using still uses the old support library, so it was in your namespace and you accidentally selected it when choosing which class to import. You need to change the line

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

to

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

in both of these files. And you need to enable Jetifier according to [these directions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio).

Comment: can u pls suggest a course of kotlin android development that i can follow

Comment: I don’t have any recommendations. I learned almost exclusively from reading the official documentation.